# Legendre symbol question for infinitely many primes of form 4k + 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a positive integer n, how would one show that there are infinitely many primes p of the form 4k + 3 that have Legendre symbol (n/p) = -1?  From the comments I have received thus far, it has been suggested to use either the Cebotorev Density Theorem or Quadratic Reciprocity to show there infinitely such primes with (n/p) = (-1/p) = -1, but I don't see how and welcome any suggestions about this.  I am asking the question for any positive integer n, though I am primarily interested in the case where n is the product of two prime numbers, where it does not happen that both of these prime numbers are congruent to 3 mod 4.

Comment: As per Bruno Joyal's answer, this question is false as stated.  However it is not hard to show that $(n/p) = (-1/p) = -1$ for infinitely many primes $p$ so long as $n$ is not a square.  Furthermore, the density of such primes is $1/4$ unless $n$ is of the form $-k^2$, in which case the density is $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you Erick--this is along the lines of what I wanted to know, but can you refer me to where I can find a proof of your statement that (n/p) = (-1/p) = -1 for infinitely many primes p as long as n is not a square, or perhaps briefly outline a proof for me?  Thanks.

Comment: @ElliotBenjamin Use the Cebotarev density theorem, or quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Thanks Bruno--I'll try that.

Comment: @ElliotBenjamin My pleasure! By the way, you should ping users using @ if you want them to be notified of your comment replies.

Comment: I'm not very tech-savy--don't know what you mean by "ping users using @" but I'll check in again tomorrow as this day is ending for me.  But I'll think about your suggestion for my Legendere problem and check tomorrow if you have some quadratic tables reference suggestion for me for my deeper Hilbert 2-class field question.  Good to converse with you.

Comment: Bruno, I slept on it and I don't see how to show this using quadratic reciprocity, which would be more understandable to me than trying to use the Cebotarev density theorem.  Can you give me a brief explanation of how to prove what Erick stated, (n/p) = (-1/p) but for inifnitely many primes p of the form 4k + 3, if this is true?  Perhaps it requires the specific conditions on n that I included in one of my edits, i.e. n is the product of two primes such that not both of these primes are congruent to 3 mod 4?  Thanks.

Comment: @ErickWong Can you give a reference on how to do it?  I need a more general statement for my research (i.e. p has to be =a (mod b) for any coprime a, b), and I'd like to see if I can generalize the statement.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is a square, then $(n/p)=1$ always.

Comment: +1.  Always except for the finitely many primes dividing $n$.

Comment: @ErickWong Indeed, good eye. I left it out because it had less of a punch ;)

Answer (score 1):

If $n=-1$ then $(n/p)= -1$ for all $4k+3$ primes

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's a special case.

Comment: I understand. The OP's question is rather vague. Does he want the condition on $n$, or a specific example? The statement is not true in general as Bruno Joyal showed.

Comment: I should probably be more specific for what I want to know.  Given n = the product of two primes, such that it's not the case that both primes are congruent to 3 mod 4, and p is a prime congruent to 3 mod 4, why are there infinitely many primes p such that the Legendre symbol (n/p) = -1?